# Simulink boost converter problem

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck-boost, simulink

I am working on a Boost converter model in Simulink for a school project.
The model should resemble charging a battery(18V) with a 12V DC voltage source and
a boost converter. With the internal resistance of the battery being
0.001ohm.
[image]

My idea is to provide a constant voltage of roughly 20 Voltage(it's only theoretical work)
I did not yet create any source of control circuit.
I have run couple simulations with different settings, and it always seems that with such small resistance, it's impossible to have higher voltages in the output.
I am always getting very low gain.

[image]
if I would increase the internal resistance to 1 ohm then I would have a high and stable voltage as an output.
I guess the low resistance is causing a big current which is causing low efficiency.
How should I deal with this issue?

Simulation settings.
Inductance = 0.01(H),Capacitance(F) = 0.1, D = 0.5, f(HZ) = 5000,Diode Ron = 0.001Ohm,FET resistance Ron = 0.1Ohm, internal

Comment: Why is your idea to boost to 20 V? With an 18 V 1 mOhm battery what current do you think will flow? Did your professor give you any guidance on how batteries are typically charged?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

you are right, that would not make any sense.
may i ask how would such arrangement be done in real situations? would the boost converter for example has to provide a very little output volage in order to maintain an acceptable charging current?

Comment: Battery charging is a complex subject.  Typically there are different phases of charging, In your case you might initially control the output current (charge current) into the battery instead of trying to regulate an output voltage.  Once the battery voltage has risen to a threshold you might switch to controlling the voltage to near the maximum battery voltage for some time then you might terminate the charge.  It's very dependent on the battery chemistry.  Not sure if your prof wanted you to go into battery charging, so maybe just picking a voltage to give you a reasonable fixed current.